# How to create individual shaped tunnel by using a curve?

Tags: objects

I try to create a square shaped tunnel with the help of a curve and a cube, i have this path curve:

[image]

And i try to use the cube to create a tunnel or closed mesh which looks something like this:

[image]

I was able to create a circle shaped tunnel by changing the object data of the curve: 
[image]

But is it possible to use individual forms to create tunnels?
I tried it with using a curve modifier in addition with an array modifier, but the result is ugly.[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by using a square shaped bezier circle (no oxymoron here as you'll soon see):

First add a bezier circle (Add --> Curve --> Circle)
[image]

Then go to edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all the control points (<kbd>A</kbd>), then press <kbd>V</kbd> --> Vector, to make all the corners sharp.

[image]

While still in edit mode, rotate the circle along the Z axis by 45 degrees (<kbd>R</kbd> --> <kbd>Z</kbd> --> 45 ).

[image]

Now use this circle as a bevel object for your tunnel curve:
[image]

Scale the circle (<kbd>S</kbd>) to adjust the size.

You can manipulate this circle to change the shape of the tunnel's profile whichever way you'd like.